# Synchronize an Android app database with a windows form application database

Tags: c#, android, sqlite, synchronization, adb

I have an app with SQLite database and I need to synchronize the data with an SQL Server or access database.
I think to 2 possible ways to do the synchronization:

1. creating a script that sends commands to adb
2. export a file using bluetooth connection

I prefer the first solution but I don't know how to send commands to adb.

The windows app is a c# program.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is to implement interprocess communication between C#.net and java-android platform.

You can use protocol buffer for serialization of interproces communication.
Protocol buffer libraries are Open source.
for more details see this 
https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto.

Ready illustration on this is available on 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640249/Android-Fast-Communication-with-NET-Using-Protocol

You can use this communication channel and **log shipping** for updating the database.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I'll try and I'll tell you if is what i'm logging for